# Why form.is_valid() always return field is required?

Tags: django, django-forms

I don't know why my form after submitting it always returns that **the phone is required**, i am stuck with this problem about one hour :(, i've seen lots of articles and questions that has been asked but without avail .

**views.py**:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            telephone = number_prettify(form.cleaned_data.get('telephone'))
            user.phone = telephone
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user.save()
            user = authenticate(phone=user.phone, password=raw_password)
            auth_login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

here is my **forms.py**:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

# from .models import Client

User = get_user_model()

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    telephone = forms.CharField(label='Номер телефона', help_text='Required. Inform a valid phone number.', 
                    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '___-__-__-__','class':"uk-input phone_us"}))

    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Пароль',widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Повторите пароль',widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    agree_1 = forms.BooleanField()
    agree_2 = forms.BooleanField()

    def clean(self):
        if not self.cleaned_data['agree_1']:
            raise forms.ValidateError('You have to agree to out privacy')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('phone',)
```

here is also the **models.py**:

```
class Client(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=18,unique=True)
    joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    password = models.CharField(default='', null=False, max_length=255)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone'

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'client'
        unique_together = ('phone',)
```

my **register.html** template:

```
<div class="uk-margin">
    <label> 
        <div class="uk-margin-small-bottom">{{form.telephone.label}} <span>*</span></div>
        {{form.telephone}}
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-margin">
    <label> 
        <div class="uk-margin-small-bottom">{{form.password1.label}} <span>*</span></div>
        {{form.password1|add_class:"uk-input"}}
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: You've made `phone` a required field but you presumably aren't supplying it in your template. You do separately define `telephone` as an extra field, perhaps you are mixing up these two field names?

Comment: please write the template html file too.

Comment: the question is updated!

Comment: change the field `telephone` from forms.py and named as `phone`

Comment: Do i have to rename it as i typed it in models.py ?? Ooooh i see, since i am using UserCreationForm not the default one, so i must name my fields as i typed them in my models, thanks dude :), it worked!!

Comment: Ok, i will write it as an official answer. ok ?

Comment: @PanosAngelopoulos, i am new to django , any way, thanks for your interest :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the field from `telephone` to `phone`.

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    phone = forms.CharField(label='Номер телефона', help_text='Required. Inform a valid phone number.', 
                    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '___-__-__-__','class':"uk-input phone_us"}))

    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Пароль',widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Повторите пароль',widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    agree_1 = forms.BooleanField()
    agree_2 = forms.BooleanField()

    def clean(self):
        if not self.cleaned_data['agree_1']:
            raise forms.ValidateError('You have to agree to out privacy')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('phone',)
```